# MDX Query in pentaho CDE

Tags: mdx, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to create a OLAP selector that includes over the fields returns, also a field that includes the sum of the other fields. How can I modify this MDX Query to solve this problem:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Name] AS 
    [Year].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
SELECT 
  Filter
  (
    {Descendants([Year].[All Years],[Year].[Year])}
   ,(NOT 
      IsEmpty([Year].CurrentMember))
  ) ON ROWS
 ,{[Measures].[Name]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [*My Table*];
```

I would that my selector shows ... "2010" "2011" "2012" "2013" "2014" and *"ALL"*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the [All] member into the set you are using on rows:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Name] AS 
    [Year].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
SELECT 
  {
    [Year].[All Years]
   ,Filter
    (
      {Descendants([Year].[All Years],[Year].[Year])}
     ,(NOT 
        IsEmpty([Year].CurrentMember))
    )
  } ON ROWS
 ,{[Measures].[Name]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [*My Table*];
```

Using the more generic name of the All member and simplifying the way you're getting hold of the year members:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Name] AS 
    [Year].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
SELECT 
  {
    [Year].[All]
   ,Filter
    (
      [Year].[Year].MEMBERS
     ,(NOT 
        IsEmpty([Year].CurrentMember))
    )
  } ON ROWS
 ,{[Measures].[Name]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [*My Table*];
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand your requirement clearly. But if you are expecting to see all the years which result from the output of the `DESCENDANTS` functions, you can try using `GENERATE`function in a calculated member.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[Years] AS
GENERATE
    (
      Filter
      (
        {Descendants([Year].[All Years],[Year].[Year])}
       ,(NOT 
          IsEmpty([Year].CurrentMember))
      )
      ,
     [Year].[Year].currentmember.member_value 
      , 
     " "
    )
```

Comment: I would like to see the years present in the olap selector (for example "2010" "2011" "2012" "2013" "2014") another field  "all" that is the sum of the other years.